# jOOQ 3.16 (and 3.16.1) breaks build

Tags: java, jooq, jooq-codegen-maven

We are currently using jOOQ 3.15.5 (Java) and everything is good. When we attempt to upgrade to 3.16.0 or 3.16.1, some of our BOOLEAN fields are represented as Object in their record java classes.

```xml
<configuration xmlns="http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.15.0.xsd">
    <generator>
        <database>
            <name>org.jooq.meta.extensions.ddl.DDLDatabase</name>
            <properties>
                <property>
                    <key>scripts</key>
                    <value>src/main/resources/db/migration/*.sql</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <key>sort</key>
                    <value>flyway</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <key>defaultNameCase</key>
                    <value>as_is</value>
                </property>
            </properties>
        </database>

        <target>
            <packageName>com.test.jooq</packageName>
            <directory>target/generated-sources/jooq</directory>
        </target>
    </generator>
</configuration>
```

The fields in our `CREATE TABLE` statement look like this:

```
is_deleted     BOOLEAN      NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE,
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Can you please show how you're generating code? (Maven configuration, source table definition (`CREATE TABLE`), etc.)? See also this resource about what I mean: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Looks like 3.16.2 is still showing the same problem for us. @LukasEder added more information to the post. Thank you.

Comment: I'm sorry I cannot reproduce this problem from what you've shown. Can you please provide a complete reproducer? If you think it's a bug, you can report one here: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/new/choose. We also have a template to create "MCVEs" (minimal, complete, verifiable examples): https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ-mcve

Comment: No worries Lukas. Thank you.

Comment: @LukasEder Seems like this is fixed in 3.16.4!! Any idea what the problem was?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce it, so I don't know

Answer (score 0):

This problem is solved in a new release: 3.16.4